# How do I autofocus a cursor in this django form?

Tags: django

In the following template, how do I force the cursor to autofocus into the form.username field when the browser loads?

---

```
{% block content %}

    <form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="login" style="position: relative; left: 5em;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </form>

    <p><a href="/register/" class="textf" style="position: relative; left: 8em;">Register</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your forms.py define the field with the autofocus attribute:

```
username = forms.CharField(
    label=_('Username'),
    strip=True,
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Username'), 'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True})
)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

Answer (score 1):

You can use [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks)

```
<td>{{ form.username|attr:"autofocus" }}</td>
```

Also it can add attributes and classes, render fields with custom template and more

Comment: Thanks you :P  How about a widget-tweak that puts the cursor at the last text box before the page was refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it with javascript (in this example, Jquery).  Make sure there is a block called extra_scripts in your base.html (just above the closing `</body>` tag), and then add the javascript as follows:

```
{% block content %}

    <form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
       </tr>
    ...
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_scripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // When the page has finished loading,
            // autofocus on the username field
            $('input#id_username').focus();
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

If you're not already using Jquery you will need to include a link to it in the page too (something like `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`).